# Does Pattern Matching in Bash use the same structure as ReGex?

Tags: regex, bash

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

I am learning Bash Pattern Matching in school and I am trying to figure out if Pattern Matching in bash have the same structure for making expressions as ReGex does.

Please advise.

Comment: No, shell pattern matching is very different from regular expressions.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching for bash filename pattern matching.

Comment: Checkout this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Answer (score 1):

It depends which "bash pattern matching" you are talking about.

- If you are talking about pathname expansion pattern matching (aka "globbing"):  No.  The syntax is different and the meta-characters mean different things.
- If you are talking about the bash `=~` operator: Yes.  This performs a form of regex matching.

For more information, read the "man bash" manual entry, etcetera.

(And of course the "expr" command can do regex matches ... though this is not strictly a bash feature.)